# scala - how to override java.util.List with scala's List() in REPL

Tags: scala, list

I'm importing java.util._ and it takes precedence when I use scala's List() collection. I have to explicitly write scala.collection.immutable.List for accessing scala's collection. How do I make the REPL use scala's List() by default, even if I import java.util._

```
scala> import java.util._

scala> val dup = List(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,100,101,101,102)

<console>:35: error: object java.util.List is not a value
       val dup = List(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,100,101,101,102)
                 ^

scala> val dup = scala.collection.immutable.List(1,1,1,2,3,4,5,5,6,100,101,101,102)

dup: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 100, 101, 101, 102)

scala>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can import everything except the `java.util.List` like this:

```
import java.util.{List => _, _}
```

Comment: how to exclude more than one package?. i'm getting error for Map also

Answer (score 1):

import scala.collection.immutable.List explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid namespace collisions, you can rename during import if you need both:

```
import java.util.{List => JList, _}
```

Comment: can you show the syntax for renaming more than one package ?

Comment: you can have multiple renames in the same line, while the final underscore will import every other name in that package as-is. Multiple renames are the following
`import java.util.{List => JList, Map => JMap, _}`. [Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Scala/Import#Renaming) is a simple and good reference on the topic.